# Laravel SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysql-error-1055

This might be obvious, and I may be completely missing the point, but I've got a table which contains multiple rows with user_id, site_id, e.g.

```
ldstaff | ld_site
____________________
   3         1
   3         2
   4         1
```

A MySQL query originally written by an old dev got the staff id find their name and then concat all the sites together to make something like this.

```
StaffID | Name | sites
  3       Dave    1,2
```

This query was written initially as

```
SELECT `ld_staff` as staffID ,a.name,GROUP_CONCAT(`ld_site`) as sites FROM `lead_distribution` l

LEFT JOIN users a ON a.crm_id = l.ld_staff

WHERE ld_enabled = 1 AND

`account_type` = 1 AND `active` = 1 AND `no_more` = 0 AND network_team > 0 AND renewal_team = 0

GROUP BY `ld_staff`
```

However whenever we try to write it in Laravel as part of a new system to get the same results we have the error **SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2** no matter how we try to tamper with the query it always comes back to this. Reading up it seems sql_mode only_full_group_by doesn't allow this type of query, so I've changed sql_mode to = " " and this error persists.

**Query**

```php
$data = DB::table('lead_distribution')
    ->join('users', 'ld_staff', '=', 'users.crm_id')
    ->select("lead_distribution.ld_staff", 'users.name', 
        DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(`ld_site`) as sites"))
    ->where('users.account_type', '=', 1)
    ->where('users.active', '=', 1)
    ->where('users.no_more', '=', 0)
    ->where('users.network_team', '>', 0)
    ->where('users.renewal_team', '=', 0)
    ->groupBy('lead_distribution.ld_staff')
    ->get();
```

Comment: to disable sql_strict mode can you try using `'strict' => false;` in your `database.php`

Comment: OH MY GOD, such a f***ing idiot, thank you

Answer (score 13):

@jaysingkar

Answer fixed it, my stupid mistake for missing it.

in `config/database.php`

Change  `'strict' => true` To `'strict' => false`

Comment: tnx but what is `strict` ?

Comment: apologies haven't logged in a while, for each database configuration inside config/database.php you can add a field called 'strict' and set it to false

Comment: Just for clarification: https://mattstauffer.com/blog/strict-mode-and-other-mysql-customizations-in-laravel-5-2/

Answer (score 3):

config/database.php

Change 'strict' => true To 'strict' => false
and clear the cache
php artisan config:cache
then issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem and got it solved by including the aggregate function in the `GROUP BY` clause.

I forgot where I have read this, but Aggregate functions must be included in the specified `sql_mode only_full_group_by` mode.

So, try using
`->groupBy(['lead_distribution.ld_staff','sites'])` or `->groupBy(['lead_distribution.ld_staff','users.name','sites'])`

A handy tip

> Try dumping the SQL Query produced by laravel by replacing `->get()` with `->toSql()` then try running the query produced by laravel and see if the error occurs.

Comment: your tip save me